# i have changed my .htaccess code after it is not displaying images

Tags: php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ page.php?page_alias=$1

RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ page.php?page_alias=$1

i have used this code for my localhost.
after it is rewriting the seo url,
but it not displaying any images.

already i tried with this

Please help me with this

Comment: Where's the problem? There is no code given to display any image?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j23feu

Comment: Please don't share code in images, and don't add relevant information to the comment section. After all, what should we guess from that image?

Comment: its displaying like as is could not load the images

Comment: my index page is displaying the the images

Comment: but i navigate to using other page is not displaying any images  but i all the header and footer as common .

Comment: Have you read and understood the link?

Comment: i cant understand properly but they saying about it get directory change please tell correct procedure

Comment: thanx bro i got it now is it working fine